# "can’t open /tmp/ccRBTake.s for writing", while compiling with gcc

Tags: c, unix

I got unusual compile time error, while I was compiling following code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    if (open("b.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0777) < 0) {
        perror("open error:");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in a directory, which doesn't contains `b.txt`.
Following is the error:

```
test.c:1:0: fatal error: can’t open /tmp/ccrlx6NY.s for writing: Permission denied
compilation terminated.
The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem.
```

I am using `GNU/Linux (3.2.0-39-generic)` operating system, and `gcc` compiler version 4.6.3.

```
$df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       44240004  10753148  31239588  26% /
udev             1004132         4   1004128   1% /dev
tmpfs             406548      1228    405320   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1016364       236   1016128   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda7       80731936  47718056  28912916  63% /home
```

What could be the exact reason, that I'm getting this message?

PS: I'm now actually getting this error on every file I compile.

Comment: Can you try a `chmod +w /tmp` and rerun the compilation?

Comment: @Ganesh I tried `chmod` still gives the same error.

Comment: Can you show us your complete command line of your compile-call?

Comment: @PatrickB.: `$gcc test.c`

Comment: Can you try `gcc -o mytest test.c` once?

Comment: @mohit .. can you please try `gcc -o mytest test.c --save-temps`?

Comment: @Ganesh Again, same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to force another tmp-dir by using the TMPDIR-environment variable:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
export TMPDIR=~/tmp
gcc test.c -o mytest
```

and check your umask-value. Try

```
umask 022
```

and invoke again your compilation-call.

Comment: The problem has been solved, `umask` on my system was somehow set to 0777. But why was I able to create files however, gcc was denied?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have write access to the `/tmp` directory. Also check that it isn't full (although that's less likely given the error message).

Are you able to create `/tmp/ccrlx6NY.s` by hand?

Comment: yeah, I've access to /tmp directory.

Comment: @mohit: Are you able to create `/tmp/ccrlx6NY.s` by hand?

Comment: yeah, I am able to create `/tmp/ccrlx6NY.s` by hand.

Answer (score 0):

gcc's C compiler outputs assembly, which is written to a temporary file (with a .s extension) that's passed to the assembler. What went wrong here is that you don't have write permissions to /tmp, so it can't write those files.

You can specify which directory gcc uses to store temporary files through the `TMPDIR` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to write to /tmp. Either chmod it or ask admin to change permissions in /tmp.

Comment: I've write permission in /tmp, as I'm able to create files.

Comment: As the same user login doing the compilation?